# Cannot use ftp with Tor

Tags: socks, torsocks

Whenever I attempt to connect to my FTP server with Tor, it rejects it.  The FTP server is using a hidden service, I must use Tor to connect to it.

What Tor says:

```
 [warn] Rejectiong SOCKS request for anonymous connection to private address [scrubbed].
```

What Filezilla says:

```
 Status:    Connecting to 127.0.0.1:9050...
 Status:    Connection with proxy established, performing handshake...
 Error: Proxy handshake failed: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted
 Response:  425 Can't open data connection for transfer of "/"
 Error: Failed to retrieve directory listing
 Response:  421 Connection timed out.
 Error: Connection closed by server
```

Is there any way to force Tor to accept my connection.

Comment: I believe it is because Tor relay operators have chosen to not allow FTP. Try using a different port for FTP. (On client and server)

Comment: Why did they choose to disallow FTP communique?

Comment: Actually, FTP isn't blocked by default. (https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#DefaultExitPorts) So it is probably not a blocked port. However, there is a chance that an individual Tor relay operator has chosen to so try again with a new circuit.

Comment: The problem with putting an FTP server behind a hidden service is that the client and the server come up with a separate connection for the data transfer. Either the FTP server has to connect back to you (after a PORT command), which would be in the clear, or the server would have to be able to supply an IP for the client to connect to (in the 227 response to the PASV command), which it doesn't know. Also, the fact that FTP wants to exchange IP addresses makes it a bad choice if you want to hide IP addresses. See if you can use HTTP or something else where control and data use one connection.

Comment: @Cammy_the_block: Aurora runs the hidden service and the FTP server. There is no exit node involved.

Comment: @jobiwan Do only exits filter ports?

Comment: @Jobiwan has answered my question.  Is there any other protocols that I can use to transfer files over Tor?   And only exits can filter ports, only they know what tcp port is being sent.

Comment: @Aurora: Personally I would look into [SSH File Transfer Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol). Then it's easy to use passwordless (public key based) authentication.