# Tor Filetransfer (FTP) for Webhoster

Tags: onion-services, network-configuration, web-hosting

I'm building a hidden service hosting provider and actually I'm able to run a web-/ and Mysql Server full proxied over the tor network. But I'm wondering how I could realize a file-transfer protocol like FTP over the tor network.

Is there any tutorial or paper about this out there? So I could create mysql, ftp access for my clients without revealing the real IP of my server. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: It can be done. I don't get the technicals but I used a hosting provider that had an ftp....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Linux, here's how I would do it.
Install vsftpd or whatever ftp server that you prefer. Make sure that your firewall is blocking it's normal port (probably port 21) to the outside.

In your /etc/tor/torrc file add a line to allow ftp to be able to be accessed via Tor:

```
HiddenServicePort 21 127.0.0.1:21
```

Then try to access it: torsocks ftp myonionxyzabc.onion.

I would suggest doing this the first time in a **temporary VM and not with your other onion services**. That way you can do your own testing without harming your onion services. If you see someplace where your IP is given away, stop the Tor service immediately in the temporary VM and research the ftp server to see if there is a way around it or try another ftp server.

Comment: This will never work. https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4878/cannot-use-ftp-with-tor#comment-4839

Comment: It does work technically in that you can set up your ftp site and login but it fails when you try to do anything with FTP because it is expecting more than just port 21. I'll reply again if I find another way.